# How to get Redux Dynamic form values without specifying the name

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, dynamic-forms, react-redux-form

I am generating my form by JSON data. Form rendering is working fine. Now i want to get the form values on submit something like below.So that i can call an API to save those values in the same submit event.

{"elementname1":"value1",
"elementname2":"value2"
"elementname2":"value2"}

Is there any way to get the values like that .

i have tried with formValueSelector  but we have to specify the element name to get the value.

Here is my code

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux'
  import { getTemplateData } from './actions';
 import autoBind from 'react-autobind';
 import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
 import { getFormValues, Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
  import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
    loadData() {
        return dispatch(getTemplateData())
    }
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps) {
  const selector = formValueSelector('create-template-form') 
return {
    ...state,
    templateData: state.templateData

}
}

 class createTemplate extends Component {

constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    autoBind(this);
    this.state = {
        topTabSelected: "details",
        leftTabSelected: "details",
        tabIndex: 0,
        dataIndex: 0
    };
    this.gotoGenRulesState = this.gotoGenRulesState.bind(this);


}
gotoGenRulesState = (data) => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'FORM_SUBMITTED',data});
}


componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadData();

}



render() {

    const renderField = ({ field, detailType}) => {
        const { type, placeholder } = field[detailType];
        if (type === 'text' || type === 'email' || type === 'number' || type === 'checkbox') {
            return <input name={detailType + field.key} {...field.input} className="form-control" placeholder={placeholder} type={type} />
        } else if (type === 'select') {
            const { options } = field
            return (
                <select name={field.name} className="form-control" onChange={field.input.onChange}>
                    {options.map((option, index) => {
                        return <option key={index} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
                    })}
                </select>
            )
        } else {
            return <div>Type not supported.</div>
        }
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.gotoGenRulesState}>
            <div>
                <div className="row" style={{ padding: "30px 80px" }} >
                    <div className="padding-sides-none col-md-12">
                        <h3 className="purple-color">Create Template</h3>

                        <div className="tabbable">

                            {this.props.templateData &&
                                <ul className="nav nav-tabs tab-nav toptab">
                                    {this.props.templateData.map((data, index) => (
                                        <li className={`${data.key === this.state.topTabSelected ? 'active' : ''}`} key={data.key + index} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} ><a onClick={() => this.openTopTab(data.key, index)}
                                            data-toggle="tab">{data.name}</a></li>
                                    ))}
                                </ul>
                            }

                            <div className="">
                                {this.props.templateData && this.props.templateData[this.state.tabIndex] &&
                                    <div className="tabbable tabs-left row">
                                        <div className="padding-sides-none col-md-4 tab-sec">
                                            <ul className="nav tab-nav">
                                                {this.props.templateData[this.state.tabIndex].subnodes.map((data, index) => (
                                                    <li key={data.key + index} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} ><a className={`${data.key === this.state.leftTabSelected ? 'detailsTitleActive' : ''}`} onClick={() => this.openDetailsTab(data.key, index)}
                                                        data-toggle="tab">{data.name}</a></li>
                                                ))}


                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-md-8 padding-sides-none inner-tab-content">
                                            <Scrollbars style={{ height: 400 }}>
                                                <div className="tab-content">

                                                    {this.props.templateData[this.state.tabIndex].subnodes[this.state.dataIndex].subnodes.map((field, index) => (

                                                        <div className={`form-group ${field.type === 'CompleteDetail' ? 'dynamic-field-inline' : ''}`} key={field.name}>
                                                            <label>{field.name}</label>
                                                            {field.detail &&
                                                                <span>

                                                                    {field.type === 'CompleteDetail' && <label>Details</label>}
                                                                    <Field
                                                                        name={`details${field.key}`}
                                                                        component={renderField}
                                                                        field={field}
                                                                        detailType='detail'
                                                                        />
                                                                </span>
                                                            }
                                                            {field.range &&
                                                                <span>
                                                                    {field.type === 'CompleteDetail' && <label>Range</label>}
                                                                    <Field
                                                                        name={'range' + field.key}
                                                                        component={renderField}
                                                                        field={field}
                                                                        detailType='range'
                                                                        />
                                                                </span>
                                                            }
                                                            {field.operator &&
                                                                <span>
                                                                    {field.type === 'CompleteDetail' && <label >Operator</label>}
                                                                    <Field
                                                                        name={'operator' + field.key}
                                                                        component={renderField}
                                                                        field={field}
                                                                        detailType='operator'
                                                                        />
                                                                </span>
                                                            }
                                                        </div>

                                                    ))}


                                                </div>
                                            </Scrollbars>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
}


createTemplate = reduxForm({
form: 'create-template-form',  // a unique identifier for this form

 })(createTemplate)



createTemplate = connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
 )(createTemplate)
```

export default createTemplate;

Answer (score 0):

Using redux form you can get all form values with `state.form.create-template-form`.

By the way you should rename your form identifier with camelCase :

```
connect(
 state => ({
  myFormValues: state.form.createTemplateForm,
 }),
)
```

And you will acces this value thanks to props `this.props.myFormValues`

Comment: i want to make service call in the submit. In the submit how can i access those values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use values when submitting, you can also do that :

```
submitFunction = (data) => {
  console.log(data) // you can use your form data here, and you don't need form name
};

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.submitFunction)}>
```

Comment: i don't have handleSubmit in the props as i not having parent component.I have tried with below also. But in the values i am not getting form data.                                                                                   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((values) => {
                console.log(values)
            })}>